# is it possible to remove a parameter between two parameters from the location or url?

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.6.1

This code results to a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, and i can't think of any other way of achieving this.

**router:**

```
.when('/:var1/:var2/:var3', {
    templateUrl : 'template.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: {
        var2: ['$route', 'serviceForVar2', function ($route, serviceForVar2) {
            return serviceForVar2.getVar2($route.current.var2);
        }]
    }
})
.when('/:var1/:var3/', {
    templateUrl : 'template.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl'
})
```

**myCtrl:**

```
function($scope, $routeParams, $location, var2) {
    if(!var2){
        $location.path('/' + $routeParams.var1+ '/' +$routeParams.var3).reload(false);
    }
}
```

so for example my current location is /en-GB/partner/china and partner is actually false from the resolve, i want to redirect it to /en-GB/china with the same controller.

Comment: Isn't simpler to switch the dynamic one to the last spot?

Comment: it would be, but i can't. coz they said the url structure would look ugly lol, i could use ?var2=value too but it would still look ugly they say.

Comment: Usually the server uses a 301 redirect to go to the preferred URL. The browser handles it automatically and there is nothing that the AngularJS client needs to do.